# how to get audio metadata using MEAN.js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, audio

I want to upload audio file (either .wav or .flac) only if it match certain Sample Rate ,Channel and bit rate. but I have few doubts in implementing this functionality?

1) is it possible with client side scripting like AngularJs?

2) If its not possible with AngularJs than its possible to get the metadata information first on server with Node.js and upload only if it matches criteria.?

Please let me know in case you need more information for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working with [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)? You don't necessarily need AngularJS and it's supported in all major browsers ([Web Audio API Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20audio)).

Comment: Another alternative would be [Aurora.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js), which also works in Node.js.